# Strong Consistency when you need to query multiple entities (thousands)

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

In an application that has many 'shops' every registered admin user has a 'shop' entity, each shop sells items where each item belongs to a certain '*category*'. Having multiple clients (100's in some cases) each client has an account to follow up on their purchases and past orders. Each shop generates invoices for their clients, clients pays the invoice.

```
Admin User -- > Shop 

Shop ---> clients
      |-> items Categories
      |-> items
      |-> invoices
      |-> payments received
```

An admin page shows a report showing invoices within the year (from Jan to Dec) this page is a client requirement. The shop is able to manually generate a new invoice when a purchase is made, and records a payment when it is paid. Note: This all happens in the actual shop, there is no online client purchases.

As a single shop generates few invoices per month (~100's), and multiple payments per month (~100's), showing this per year easily goes to thousands entities to show on a single page.

To optimize loading the page and generating the sales year report (total sales, revenue, payment...etc.), we thought we'd structure the data in a way where each *item category per year* is also an entity. This means that whenever a purchase is made for an item in this category, we need to add the item's purchase price to the *itemCategory* at that year in this month.

*itemCategory* Model:

```
itemCategory(ndb.Model):
    shopID = ndb.KeyProperty()
    year = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    monthly_sales = ndb.FloatProperty(repeated=True) #12 months
```

This way we can load the entire sales table by reading just the list of *itemCategory* for this shop for this year, instead of reading all individual purchases through the year. This would save lots of Datastore reads and decrease page load time on the expense of an extra read, sum & write to this summary like entity.

```
Category      Jan   Feb   Mar ... Dec
--------------------------------------
Men's shoes   1000  1300  850 ... 1400
Kids shoes     600   850  650 ...  900
```

The challenge at this point is that strong consistency is quite essential, for individual purchases and for the itemCategory entities. Because if the shop tries to add multiple purchases in a successive short timed way, with eventual consistency itemCategory might have not been updated with the last purchase sum yet. Resulting in wrong sales values. Also the same for individual purchase if there was a requirement to edit one right after it was added, a query for the entity without its ID might have no results. So it seems that Ancestor queries is essential here with maybe the shop as the parent entity. Yet, this will result in a contention issue later on (at least until Datastore is migrated to Firestore) with all those entities (thousands in this case!) having one single parent!

The same goes for invoices, generating a new invoice means knowing the latest invoice number so that they are always in sequence without gaps. Querying invoice with eventual consistency may result in duplicate invoice numbers.

What is the optimum way to structure the data at this point for strong consistency? Unfortunately the project has been there for a few years, and was started using Google Datastore rather than Cloud SQL (which seem to be more appropriate for this kind of projects). Hopefully all these issues goes away after the migration to Firestore having Strong consistency for all reads

Answer (score 1):

Consider exporting the data and then importing it into a Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode project. No more eventual consistemcy issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain ways you can achieve strong consistency.

1. Query using `key`. Whenever you try to read an object via its key it is `strongly consistent`.
2. Another approach would be to use NDB Asynchronous Operations. See related [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) here.
3. A really naive approach would be to provide a delay which could help you but the delay should be provided in such a way that it is sufficient for the object to get updated.
4. And the final approach could be to export data into Cloud Firestore. There you can achieve strong consistency always.

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Comment: Hi.. 1) Unfortunately I can not get by key, need to 'query' through the DB entities and that's eventual consistency. 2) NDB Asynchronous Operations is a non blocking fetch request, but does not ensure strong consistency as far as I know. 3) I don't think this is practical on prod. 4) I was hoping to find a way around this at least until the auto migration takes place :)